# Load test automation as part of VSTS release pipeline

Tags: performance, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to automate the load testing for one of mine Azure app services API suite. I was able to create a VSTS release pipeline which will do on-demand provision of performance environment (Azure resources) and was able to add load test as a step (VSTS release task) which will invoke a cloud load test.

The next step that i am trying to achieve is to have multiple cloud based load test for each region with a variable load pattern running as part of the same release pipe line in parallel to mimic a concurrent load from multiple region but unfortunately a load test task seems to be only for one load test file. Is there a way we can configure multiple load test in a single task. Any thing am missing or any thoughts on this entire process in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t specify multiple load test files in a [load test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/cloud-based-load-test?view=vsts).

You can put multiple load test tasks in a [task group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=vsts).

On the other hand, you can refer to the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/RunLoadTestV1) to custom build/release task to meet your requirement. [Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts)

Comment: Thanks!! On the second point of using task group (multiple task packaged together as one task group) is their a configuration to run them in parallel?

Comment: No, the tasks in task group can't be run in parallel, I recommend that you can custom build task.